# Displaying random text using SKLabelNode

Tags: ios, skspritenode, sklabelnode

I'm new to this sprite kit.I want to display the text randomly.Actually i'm having 3 words i need to display those 3 words randomly using SKLabelNode.I don't know how to implement this.Let us take Air,Land and sea these 3 words should be randomly displayed .please help me regarding this issue.Thanks in Advance.

```
 SKLabelNode  * scoreLbl =  [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Futura-Bold"];
[scoreLbl setText:@"Sea"];



[scoreLbl setFontSize:50*_distanceMultiPlayer];


[scoreLbl setPosition:CGPointMake(scoreLbl.position.x, scoreLbl.position.y + (10 *_distanceMultiPlayer) )];
scoreLbl.fontColor=[UIColor blueColor];
[scoreLbl setFontSize:12.0];
[self     addChild:scoreLbl];
[scoreLbl setName:@"scoreLabel"];
```

Comment: Can i know the reason for down vote and also if u know the answer please reply me?

Comment: you want to show these words  one by one after some time intervals ?      https://github.com/ioscreator/ioscreator see this tutorial may help you

Comment: Not time interval but i'm developing a game when i click a ball it should display one text after that ball moves the text should change

Comment: please check my updated code how to take 3 texts..should we use array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scoreLbl.text = @[@"Air", @"Land", @"Sea"][arc4random() % 3];
```

Comment: Sorry the text is not displaying @Droppy.please help me to solve this issue

Comment: @AppDeveloper I've update my answer; you need to use the `text` property, not the `name` property.

Comment: Thanq I got it we need to give label.text

Answer (score 1):

I Got the answer.I have given my code as   scoreLbl.text= @[@"Air", @"Land", @"Sea"][arc4random() % 3];

Thank guys for helping me

Comment: That is not how things are done here on stackoverflow.

Comment: By mistake this was happened @Droppy.Can you please help me for other issue?

Comment: @Droppy Sorry by mistake.Can you please solve my other issue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30996459/issue-with-calendar-events-and-remainders-while-running-in-device

Comment: please check this .i'm able to save event if I'm using simulator but if I'm using device it's not saving..:(